# fatal: Invalid refspec '+refs/heads/*'

Tags: git

In [git-fetch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) doc, you can see:

> The remote ref that matches <src> is fetched, and if <dst> is not
>   ***empty string***, the local ref that matches it is fast-forwarded using
>   <src>. If the optional plus + is used, the local ref is updated even
>   if it does not result in a fast-forward update.

So we can use `empty string as destination`. Now my current repository has a remote which it's name is `origin`. When I try to fetch like this, I get an error:

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/*
fatal: Invalid refspec '+refs/heads/*'
```

But why an `empty string` cause `invalid refspec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refspec descriptions in all of the git documentation are generally a bit poor, in part because all this stuff evolved over time and the current best practice refspecs were only invented for git version 1.5, with older methods still being supported today.

In any case, shell glob style `*` matches are limited ([less so in git 2.6](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.6.0.txt) than they were before).  One limitation is requiring full pairs: That is, you cannot use a wildcard match `*` on the left side of a fetch refspec without having a corresponding `*` on the right.  This is why git winds up rejecting your empty refspec, even though it *should* logically work on the command line (in that it should be able to drop any matching ref into `FETCH_HEAD`).

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to fetch like this, I get an error:

You don't need to supply information to the fetch this way.

You can use it like this (no need to define the ref themself):

```
# fetch all ref
git fetch 

# fetch a specific ref
git fetch origin
```

> The format of a  parameter is an optional plus +, followed by the source ref , followed by a colon :, followed by the destination ref . The colon can be omitted when  is empty.

Comment: You try to fetch branches while fetch update remotes. `refs/heads` are branches  and not remotes

Comment: But we can use `$ git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` without any error.

Comment: This is the default. If you will edit the `.git/config` you will see this line in there,

Comment: So `+refs/heads/*` must be a valid refspec for `fetch`.

Comment: It is but you cant use the * in this format., if you will specify a single branch it should work `+refs/heads/master`

Comment: Why  I can not use `*` in that format? Any reference to docs is good.